# PHP CURL PUT Equivalent to Command Line

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am working on a PHP webservice that will be making REST calls to an application API.  My webservice is built on a LAMP server running ubuntu and the following command is working perfect from command line:

> curl -k -u username -H "Content-type: application/xml" -X PUT -d @request.xml https://server/path/

However, when I try to build the same request in PHP I am getting the following response from the REST server, indicating that the XML is missing:

> HTTP400Premature end of file.

Here is the code of my PHP request:

```
$ch2 = curl_init($service_url);
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'Accept: application/xml');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch2);
```

Everything I have read indicates the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is the place to do this, but I thought this was for adding "?" variables to the actual URL.  Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `man curl` and look at `-XPUT` and `-d`

Comment: Hi Sammitch, what I'm looking for is the PHP equivalent though.  I'll check it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-parameters), if you use *CURLOPT_PUT* you should also provide *CURLOPT_INFILE* and *CURLOPT_INFILESIZE*.

Maybe instead of

```php
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
```

try

```php
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen('request.xml', 'r'));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('request.xml'));
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Now I need to figure out how to have it use XML created by code instead of a file, but I'm sure that's not going to be hard.